# Can I get a clean data structure with aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an aggregation but the results are bloated with metadata and not fits my use case.

This is my aggregation definition;

```
"aggs": {
  "attributes": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "attributes"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "facet_name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "attributes.name.keyword"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "facet_value": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "attributes.value.keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**I try to get a data structure similar to this;**

```
[{
  "name": "Materiał",
  "values": ["stal", "drewno"...] 
},
{
  "name": "Kolor",
  "values": ["czarny", "kolorowy"...]
]
```

Instead of this results set below which is the current aggregation response;

```
"aggregations" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "doc_count" : 142307,
      "facet_name" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 38074,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Materiał",
            "doc_count" : 21811,
            "facet_value" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 4977,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "stal",
                  "doc_count" : 3141
                },
                {
                  "key" : "drewno",
                  "doc_count" : 2944
                },
                {
                  "key" : "szkło",
                  "doc_count" : 2885
                },
                {
                  "key" : "tworzywo sztuczne",
                  "doc_count" : 1529
                },
                {
                  "key" : "metal",
                  "doc_count" : 1303
                },
...
```

This is the closest result that I could get.

I couldn't find how to restructure the resulting object or remove the metadata from aggregations.

Comment: Please be more specific about the desired response. What do you mean with *metadata*? Some fields that you dont want to have included in the response? Which ones would they be?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill Thanks for your comment. I edited the question more understandable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuanetly you can not change the structure of the response body to fulfill your desired result. This is just how the Elasticsearch REST API is implemented.

You would have to iterate over the buckets array and create your own structure/object by extracting the particular values.